# Find an element in an XML tree using ElementTree

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

I am trying to locate a specific element in an XML file, using ElementTree. Here is the XML:

```
<documentRoot>
    <?version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <n:CallFinished xmlns="http://api.callfire.com/data" xmlns:n="http://api.callfire.com/notification/xsd">
        <n:SubscriptionId>96763001</n:SubscriptionId>
        <Call id="158864460001">
            <FromNumber>5129618605</FromNumber>
            <ToNumber>15122537666</ToNumber>
            <State>FINISHED</State>
            <ContactId>125069153001</ContactId>
            <Inbound>true</Inbound>
            <Created>2014-01-15T00:15:05Z</Created>
            <Modified>2014-01-15T00:15:18Z</Modified>
            <FinalResult>LA</FinalResult>
            <CallRecord id="94732950001">
                <Result>LA</Result>
                <FinishTime>2014-01-15T00:15:15Z</FinishTime>
                <BilledAmount>1.0</BilledAmount>
                <AnswerTime>2014-01-15T00:15:06Z</AnswerTime>
                <Duration>9</Duration>
            </CallRecord>
        </Call>
    </n:CallFinished>
</documentRoot>
```

I am interested in the `<Created>` item. Here is the code I am using:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

calls_root = ET.fromstring(calls_xml)
    for item in calls_root.find('CallFinished/Call/Created'):
        print "Found you!"
        call_start = item.text
```

I have tried a bunch of different XPath expressions, but I'm stumped - I cannot locate the element. Any tips?

Comment: Your XML document looks odd. It seems the second line `<?version...` should be the very first line.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't referencing the namespaces that exist in the XML document, so ElementTree can't find the elements in that XPath. [You need to tell ElementTree what namespaces you are using.](http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm)

The following should work:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

namespaces = {'n':'{http://api.callfire.com/notification/xsd}',
             '_':'{http://api.callfire.com/data}'
            }
calls_root = ET.fromstring(calls_xml)
    for item in calls_root.find('{n}CallFinished/{_}Call/{_}Created'.format(**namespaces)):
        print "Found you!"
        call_start = item.text
```

Alternatively, [LXML has a wrapper around ElementTree and has good support for namespaces without having to worry about string formatting](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces).