# ElementTree cannot find element

Tags: python, elementtree

I have an XML document, for which I'm including a sufficient subset in the reproducer below, for which `tree.find()` returns no results:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str = '''
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
   <System/>
</Event>
'''

tree = ET.fromstring(xml_str)
system = tree.find('System')
```

I expect `system` to hold the `<System>` tag now, but it is `None`. Am I missing something here?

When I used array indices (like `tree[0][0]`) it did work.

Comment: It's not a `System` tag, it's a `{http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event}System` tag. Namespaces matter.

Comment: Likely duplicative of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127119/find-an-element-in-an-xml-tree-using-elementtree

Comment: ...edited the reproducer to make it fully copy/paste friendly (previously, the documented needed to be fixed up before it would parse, thus not being verifiable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the namespace in your search:

```
>>> doc.find('{http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event}System')
<Element {http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event}System at 0x10167e5a8>
```